# How can I see available styles for a react native component

Tags: react-native

Where in the docs can I figure out if a particular style is applicable to a particular component.

E.g; if I want to use backgroundColor on a Button component, where I can see if it's a valid style?

Comment: You can find it in official website of react native which is : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first thing, the `Button` component doesn't use a style prop. There's only minimal customisation you can do, and if you want a custom button you need to build it yourself, as stated in the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button

If you take a look in the left hand column of the docs above, you'll find all the components you can use in React Native. In each one you'll find the `style` prop if it's supported, e.g. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#style

From here you can click on the value under `Type`, in this case `view styles`, and it will take you to a list of styles you can use for that component.

This process is a bit cumbersome, the main differences to remember are what applies to text vs. non-text components. You can set up your IDE to auto-suggest react-native styles, and then as long as you remember whether you're dealing with a text or non-text component it should be quite easy.